# How can I change an object's argument without having to create a new object?

Tags: python

```
while jogador1_hp > 30:
    enemy1_atk = random.randrange(1, 250)
    enemy1 = Enemy1(enemy1_atk)
    enemy1_atkk = enemy1.getAttk()
    jogador1_hp = jogador1_hp - enemy1_atkk

    if jogador1_hp <= 30:
        jogador1_hp = 30

    print("You got hit and you lost ", enemy1_atkk, " hp. Your HP its now", jogador1_hp)

    if jogador1_hp > 30:
        continue

    print("Gods protected you by teleporting you to the nearest INN")
    break
```

In this exercise, i want to create an "enemy" and i want his attack to be random every time it attacks. If i create the enemy object within the while loop, every time it loops it creates a new object or it creates the same object again?

Is there a way to create the object outside the loop and still be able to change his "attack" every time it loops again?

EDIT: this is my enemy class

```
class Enemy1:
    def __init__(self, atkp):
        self.atkp = atkp

    def getAttk(self):
        return self.atkp
```

EDIT2: Thanks for your replies, i manage to fix it. It goes like this now:

```
class Enemy1:
    def __init__(self, atkp):
        self.atkp = atkp




jogador1 = Player1(300)
jogador1_hp = jogador1.getBHP()
enemy1_atk = random.randrange(1, 250)
nemy1 = Enemy1(enemy1_atk)

while jogador1_hp > 30:
    enemy1_atk = random.randrange(1, 250)
    jogador1_hp = jogador1_hp - enemy1_atk
```

Comment: I've got a suggestion for your print statement in your original code.  You can use string formatting to really easily assemble strings: `print("You got hit and you lost {} hp. Your HP its now {}".format(enemy1_atkk, jogador1_hp))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you create an instance of the enemy class inside the loop, you'll get a new instance with each loop iteration.

```
enemy1 = Enemy1(enemy1_atk)
while jogador1_hp > 30:
    # the rest of your code
```

would create the enemy before your loop runs and then any time you reference `enemy1` inside the loop, it would be the same instance.

Python doesn't have private class attributes (variables).  Because of this, you don't really need the `getAttk` method in the `Enemy` class.  You can access the `atkp` attribute directly.  If you wanted access to `enemy1`'s `atkp` attribute, all you'd have to do is

```
enemy1.atkp = x
```

Because of easily being able to access the enemy's attack, there's probably also no need for the `enemy1_atkk` variable.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new object every time. If you want to get a random value each time from the same object just have the object create the random value.

```
import random


class Enemy(object):

    @staticmethod
    def get_attack():
        return random.randrange(1, 250)
```

Then create the object outside of your loop.